# How to remove the white margin?

Tags: prestashop

Recently, I've noticed that my theme has a white margin on the right side and I don't want it. I've posted an image so that you see what I'm talking about. Do you know whu this white stripe is there and how I can remove it?

[image: http://oi59.tinypic.com/k9taur.jpg]

Comment: Don't know, use the Firebug to inspect your page elements and you will see.

Comment: maybe you shoud give us the URL or more information?

Answer (score 1):

I conducted tests with javascript capturing document sizes, tested many sizes and came to the result that less than 1260px in the blank begins to appear.

For example, with 1259px, the space 1px arm appeared. The maximum size that it achieves is about 60px. Thus, leaving the minimum size of html with 1260px, at least for me, the blank did not show up anymore.

In your theme, open global.css file, in the end of file add this line:

```
html{
 min-width:1260px;
}
```

Comment: What's the significance of the number `1260`?

Comment: 1260px is the minimum width for <html> tag in the prestashop. If it is less than 1260px then appears white space to the right. 

Worked fine with me.

Comment: Ah! You might want to include that in the answer (to my untrained eyes it looked like a Magic Number). This would improve your answer as you'd be providing the *why* as well as the *how*.

Comment: I conducted tests with javascript capturing document sizes, tested many sizes and came to the result that less than 1260px in the blank begins to appear. For example, with 1259px, the space 1px arm appeared. The maximum size that it achieves is about 60px. 

Thus, leaving the minimum size of html with 1260px, at least for me, the blank did not show up anymore.

Comment: Again, that's the sort of useful information that should be included in the answer - hit edit and add it in! As an aside (take this with a pinch of salt - this isn't my area of expertise), could this value be affected by your screen size/resolution?

Comment: JonK, Thanks for the tip! Already includes the comment on my answer! 

The value will only be 1260px afeteado if the screen resolution is higher than 1260px, 1260px as defined as "minimum width" if your resoução is bigger then the width will be 100% of the document.